# rsync all directories that start with a specific digit

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I have directory loaded with thousands of sub directories:

```
/home/tmp/
          1
          12
          123
          1234
          2345
          234
          3456
          345
          34
```

Each subdirectory in turn has hundreds of subdirectories that I want to rsync if the first level subdirectory matches...

What I need is a way to copy/rsync only the directories that start with a given digit [1-9]...

What I think I want is basically something that would allow me to use wild cards to match

```
rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1* /home/tmp/
```

I want rsync to sync up the

```
/home/tmp/1/
/home/tmp/12/
/home/tmp/123/
/home/tmp/1234/
```

directories and any child subdirectories they have but not any of the first level directories that start with a different digit...

```
/home/tmp/234/
/home/tmp/2345/
........./3*/
........./4*/ etc..
```

**What I've tried:**

```
rsync -rzvvhP --exclude='*' --include-from=1.txt remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

where 1.txt contains:

```
1
12
123
1234
```

When I do this with 2.txt though rsync still seems to run through all the directories that start with 1 and 3 etc...

**I just tried:**

```
rsync -rzvvhP --include-from=2.txt remoteaccount@remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
first I get....
[sender] showing directory 2758 because of pattern 2758
```

... which seems good, but then I get....

```
1014/135954/T33-2.JPG is uptodate
1014/135956/456309.jpg is uptodate
```

... which is bad

**per a suggestion I tried:**

```
rsync -rzvvhP --size-only --filter='+ /2*/ - /*' remoteuser@remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

When that runs the first thing I get is a bunch of "uptodate" lines for files that shouldn't be part of this rsync:

```
1001/149984/T3201-2.JPG is uptodate
```

How can I do this so that I can have one command to rsync only the directories that start with any given digit?

Comment: Your idea of using text files with lists of directories should have worked. Did you try removing the `--exclude='*'`?

Comment: Yes I did...the exclude was added after that only because rsync (with the verbosity set higher) keeps saying that its running through all the directories starting with other digits.

Comment: whatever the answer is but its going to be very interesting.. nice question

Comment: I got it to work!
rsync -rzvvhP --include-from=2.txt --exclude="/*" remoteaccount@remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create filter file, like this:

/my/dir/include.txt

```
+ /1*/
+ /3*/

# Skip everything else
- /*
```

now add this to rsync

```
rsync -rzvvhP \
    --filter='merge /my/dir/include.txt' \
    remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as the thing I mentioned I tried where I put the --include-from="2.txt"  the output is the same...first it says: [sender] showing directory 2758 because of pattern /2*/  and then it runs through all the files and gives...1014/135954/T33-2.JPG is uptodate etc..

Comment: @kasdega. You've never shown us 2.txt

Comment: sorry I thought that was implied...in the example provided above 2.txt contains:
2345
234  In my real world 2.txt contains all the directory names that start with 2 one per line.
2999
2998
2997
2996
2995
2993
2992
2991

Comment: @kasdega. Sorry, forgot about blanket skip rule at the end of filter file.

Comment: same result.  The exact command I'm running right now (minus my username and ip address) is:
 rsync -rzvvhP --size-only --filter='+ /2*/ - /*' remoteuser@remotehost:/home/tmp/ /home/tmp/    The first thing I get is a bunch of "uptodate" lines: 1001/149984/T3201-2.JPG is uptodate

Comment: @kasdega.  If you remove undesirable subdirectories from the target directory, do they get copied from the source?

Comment: I removed the 1001 directory, ran the previously mentioned command and the 1001 directory is back.

Comment: ha I got it!  your answer helped but the answer was to use the file thing I did before but to add --exclude="/*"

Comment: your answer helped but it wasn't exactly what was needed.  the --exclude using the "/*" was the answer...if you change your answer to reflect that then I'd be happy to accept the answer and give you credit for it.

Comment: @kasdega. Actually, this specification `--filter='+ /2*/ - /*'` is wrong, and not what I suggested in my answer.  The man page specifically says that `--filter` option can only take one rule at a time (you can specify `--filter` multiple times though).  Did you ever try my example as it's written, with filter rules in its own file, containing both include and exclude rules?

Comment: I did and it didn't work...the trick was to use your filter rules --filter='/2*/' AND an additional switch of --exclude='/*'

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, because you say

> What I think I want is basically something that would allow me to use wild cards to match
>
> ```
> rsync -rzvvhP remotehost:/home/tmp/1* /home/tmp/
> ```

but this just simply works.

Let's see what's on the remotehost.

```
$ ssh remotehost find /tmp/a -type f
/tmp/a/123/x/a
/tmp/a/123/x/c
/tmp/a/123/y/b
/tmp/a/12/x/a
/tmp/a/12/x/c
/tmp/a/12/y/b
/tmp/a/1/x/a
/tmp/a/1/x/c
/tmp/a/1/y/b
/tmp/a/23456/x/a
/tmp/a/23456/x/c
/tmp/a/23456/y/b
/tmp/a/234/x/a
/tmp/a/234/x/c
/tmp/a/234/y/b
/tmp/a/34567/x/a
/tmp/a/34567/x/c
/tmp/a/34567/y/b
/tmp/a/3456/x/a
/tmp/a/3456/x/c
/tmp/a/3456/y/b
/tmp/a/345/x/a
/tmp/a/345/x/c
/tmp/a/345/y/b
/tmp/a/34/x/a
/tmp/a/34/x/c
/tmp/a/34/y/b
/tmp/a/3/x/a
/tmp/a/3/x/c
/tmp/a/3/y/b
```

And now rsync only directories starting with 2. Depending on your shell you may need to quote the wildcard, as I do here, or not need to do it. Under bash this should not be necessary.

```
$ rsync -rzvvhP 'remotehost:/tmp/a/2*' .
opening connection using: ssh remotehost rsync --server --sender -vvrze.iLsf . "/tmp/a/2*"
receiving incremental file list
delta-transmission enabled
234/
234/x/
234/x/a
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=7/12)
234/x/c
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=6/12)
234/y/
234/y/b
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=5/12)
23456/
23456/x/
23456/x/a
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=2/12)
23456/x/c
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=1/12)
23456/y/
23456/y/b
       8 100%    7.81kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=0/12)
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=48

sent 149 bytes  received 533 bytes  454.67 bytes/sec
total size is 48  speedup is 0.07
```